# Decision Tree Error for different length

Tags: python

I tried to calculate the test and training error for a decision tree for different depth.

```
train_error = []
test_error = []    
for i in range (3,21):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(womendata, womeny, test_size=0.4, random_state=1 )
    decitiontree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini', splitter='best', max_depth=i, class_weight = 'balanced', min_samples_split=i)
    clf = decitiontree.fit(X_train, y_train)
    train_error.append( 1 -  clf.score(X_train, y_train)  )     
    test_error.append( 1 -  clf.score(X_test, y_test)  )
```

In python 3 I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 154, in fit
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 398, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 54, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Both womendata en women y are of the same length, and there are no missing data in the set.

Answer (score 0):

from the error you providing your data arrays containing invalid value.

> ValueError: Input contains **NaN, infinity** or a value **too large** for
>   dtype('float32').

please check that your data is valid meaning:

1. no NaN values on the womendata or womeny
2. no Inf values on the womendata or womeny
3. values are inside the range of float32 min and float32 max

you can use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
info = np.finfo(np.float64)

for x in [womendata, womeny]:
    assert np.all(x <= info.max) and np.all(x >= info.min), 'not all values in range'
    assert np.all(x != np.inf) and np.all(x != -np.inf), 'data contains infinity value'
    assert np.all(x is not np.nan), 'data contains Nan value'
```